# Unable to pass laravel array on to the view

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array that i want to return from the controller to the view.But unable to retrieve that.
If i dump my array it looks like this:

```
array:121 [▼
  0 => array:10 [▼
    "ProcedureName" => "eye"
    "Status" => "referred"
    "PreferredDate" => "12/12/2018"
    "PreferredCity" => "Bangalore"
    "BookingId" => "EZBK000126"
    "Documents" => ""
    "Name" => "vik kon"
    "Age" => 62
    "Gender" => "male"
    "Mob" => "1110002223"
  ]
  1 => array:10 [▼
    "ProcedureName" => "eye"
    "Status" => "referred"
    "PreferredDate" => "12/12/2018"
    "PreferredCity" => "mysore"
    "BookingId" => "EZBK000125"
    "Documents" => ""
    "Name" => "vik kon"
    "Age" => 62
    "Gender" => "male"
    "Mob" => "9146178526"
  ]
```

So i want to get it to show inside my view .Currently my code looks like this :

```
@foreach($new_records as $new_recordss)

    <tr>

      <td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss->ProcedureName }}</td>

      <td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss->Status }}</td>

      <td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss->Age }}</td>

      <td scope="col"><div class="btn-group">

   </div>
 </td>


    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

But this gives the following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: share controller method , how you are passing `$new_records` to view ? It seems array not object

Comment: @gaan10 Yes please share the controller method.

Comment: Why should he? The error is `Trying to get property of non-object` which completely makes sense given the provided code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because an array is not an object.

```
// -> is for object
<td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss->ProcedureName }}</td>

// [] is for array
 <td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['ProcedureName'] }}</td>
```

Thus this should work:

```
<td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['ProcedureName'] }}</td>
<td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['Status'] }}</td>
<td scope="col">{{ $new_recordss['Age'] }}</td>
```

Comment: No problem. Consider to tick as an answer so other people can benefit!

Comment: sure,will do that

Answer (score 1):

The reason why

```
{{ $new_recordss->ProcedureName }}
```

would not work is because -> operator is used to access an Object. Notice that you get the following error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Because you have an array with 121 arrays in it. Therefore in order to access this associative array, you would use

```
{{ $new_recordss['ProcedureName'] }}
```

Here, the 'ProcedureName' is simply the key name and we are telling the array to fetch it's value. I hope this answers your question.